# Creating a separate wordpress home page and blog

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hello I want to Create a home page that has updating blog entries.
So 4 lists of headlines from different categories

And I want to have a link to the regular blog page with a different template.

Right now I just changed index.php around to have the containers for the featured posts content.

So this is a two part question how do I get these mini updates for the thing
I want to use query_posts() multiple times I assume and separate by category.

And how do I make a linkable page to a blog.php file which currently is telling me that all these functions are undefined.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a page that includes WP data/posts outside the themes or blog folder, you need to include and make available the Wordpress functions first:

```
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
    require('./blog/wp-blog-header.php');
```

And then you can make the queries for each set of posts by category:

```
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '5, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 'your category ID' );
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach($myposts as $post) {
    ...some code...
    }
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I actually asked this question in WP stack which I wish crossed over for, still gave you the answer here.    http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26354/best-practice-for-displaying-categorized-posts-on-front-page